# Looking for an app to track all foods eaten and how I felt

Tags: android, data-analysis, data, health

I am looking for an app (It should work on Android and ideally on Windows or browsers) to be able to precisely track all foods eaten.

I am not interested in anything too complex, and I do not want the app to inform me about the calories, proteins or anything else. I just want to be able to know exactly all the things that I ate on one particular day.

I have tried several apps, most of them *habit trackers*, but they are somewhat limited in what they offer.

As an example, say I eat pasta with tomato sauce and oregano. I want to be able to input all these ingredients. Then they should be saved in the app so that the next time I eat them I can easily select them.

Ideally it should allow me to track the different things that I ate and track several health related values.

Comment: You really added a tag for `eat`??!! And with only 11 rep?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the 'youate' android app in the play store. It provides a visual timeline of the foods you have eaten, relating that to your health and allows you to store notes on recipes.

The only 'food diary' that I know of that, that also has a web app is MyFitnessPal but it doesn't meet your criteria as it's complicated and focused on calorie counting.

Answer (score 1):

I used [Food Diary](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.food.diary&hl=en) some years ago to track all I ate and the exercise I did. It has a handy export to .xls if bringing to a nutritionist, etc. The simple and straightforward layout in diary form is excellent. the reviews will back me up.

The developer is approachable is the current feature set does not include a how you feel capture.

From the site:

- Built-in Calendar : our Food Diary provides you a calendar to jump to any day you want to see your food tracker history or edit it.
- Easy navigation between days: if you want to see or edit your food tracker history just swipe to the right
- Has exercise, medication, supplements, food journal : Food Diary offers you other entries types such as medication, supplements, exercise ….